# Generalized birthday problem (or continuous capture recapture?)

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Let's say I don't know how many days there are in a year (N) and want to figure this out by asking people for their birthday.

I ask D random people for their birthday and find there are E duplicate birthdays. How can I estimate N?

For example, say I draw:
24, 49, 52, 28, 28, 54, 59, 50, 23, 44, 49, 46, 29, 24, 52

Here, D=15 (15 draws) and E=4 (the numbers 24, 28, 49 and 52 appear twice). What is N?

Comment: Some clarifying questions: Do you know the actual draws, or do you only know the number of draws and the number of duplicates?  If you know the actual draws, do you know that they come from the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$ for some unknown $N$?

Comment: You don't have some kind of an ordered set.

Comment: A bit more clarification: the set is not of consecutive numbers. All you know is that different members have a different tag/number.

Comment: So, in other words, there is no point in knowing the actual numbers.  All you have is the number of draws and the pattern of duplicates?  (I.e., you know how many birthdays have been drawn more than once, and how many times each has been drawn.)

Comment: Do you get to know, for example, how many birthdays (if any) were drawn three times, or in general $m$ times for any $m$?

Comment: you know how many birthdays appeared once, twice, etc.
Another way of looking at this question is to estimate population size from observations: you're in a party and want to estimate the number of guests.
So, you go to the bar and record each patron that gets a drink (e.g. write down her name). Let's assume uniform random probability all over the place (the probability someone approaches the bar doesn't depend on whether he already has a drink in hand).

So - after N pints of beer, you find you served E different patrons, D of those came for a second round (bonus question - deal 3+ rounds)