# Estimating population size based on repeats

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

In https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14964/estimate-population-size-based-on-repeated-observation we want to estimate the size of a population based on the first repeat observation:

> Suppose the first k buses are all different, but on day k+1 I take one I've been on before. What is the best estimate for the total number of buses?

But what if we don't stop after the first repeat? After some additional observations another bus would appear again, then another. At some point a bus will appear for a *3rd* time, etc.

So, given a set of observations, what can we say about the distribution of possible population sizes?

(this is the same question I was trying to ask in [Generalized birthday problem (or continuous capture recapture?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522742/generalized-birthday-problem-or-continuous-capture-recapture). I hope this version is clearer)